# element.getElementsByClassName is not a function

Tags: javascript, display, getelementsbyclassname

Currently I'm working in card filter, but I get `jobCards[card].getElementsByClassName is not a function.`

```
const cardHasRequirementFilter = function(card){

    for(let requirementInFilter in listForFiltering){
        let requirementsByCard = jobCards[card].getElementsByClassName("job-requirements__requirement");
        for(let requirementInCard in requirementsByCard){
            if(requirementInCard.innerHTML === requirementInFilter.innerHTML ){
                return true;
            }
        }  
    }

    return false;
}
```

When I call that function i do it this way

```
jobCards[card].style.display = cardHasRequirementFilter(card)===true?"flex":"none";
```

I tried with:

```
jobCards[card].style.display = cardHasRequirementFilter(jobCards[card])===true?"flex":"none";


const cardHasRequirementFilter = function(card){

    for(let requirementInFilter in listForFiltering){
        let requirementsByCard = card.getElementsByClassName("job-requirements__requirement");
        for(let requirementInCard in requirementsByCard){
            if(requirementInCard.innerHTML === requirementInFilter.innerHTML ){
                return true;
            }
        }  
    }

    return false;
}
```

And i get the same error...

I tried on Edge and chrome.

**All my code is:**

```
const btnsRequirements = document.getElementsByClassName("job-requirements__requirement");
const jobCards = document.getElementsByClassName("job-list__card-job");

/* All non repetible requirements existent. */
const listRequirements = {};

/* The cards will be filtered by this requirements to be 
filtered, if it's empty, then all cards will be shown.  */
const listForFiltering = {};



for (let requirement of btnsRequirements) {

    let text = requirement.innerHTML;
    listRequirements[text] = text;/* Creates a new property with the same value, if already existe, it's overited. */

    requirement.addEventListener("click", function () {

        let requirementClicked = this.innerHTML;
        listForFiltering[requirementClicked] = requirementClicked;
        filterCardsByRequirementsChoosed();

    }, false);

}

const filterCardsByRequirementsChoosed = function(){
    let numEntries = Object.entries(listForFiltering).length;
    if ( numEntries === 0){
        /* if there's no filter, then show all. */
        for(let card of jobCards){
            jobCards[card].style.display = "flex";
        }
    }else{
        for(let card in jobCards){
            jobCards[card].style.display = cardHasRequirementFilter(card)===true?"flex":"none";
        }
    }

};

const cardHasRequirementFilter = function(card){

    for(let requirementInFilter in listForFiltering){
        let requirementsByCard = jobCards[card].getElementsByClassName("job-requirements__requirement");
        for(let requirementInCard in requirementsByCard){
            if(requirementInCard.innerHTML === requirementInFilter.innerHTML ){
                return true;
            }
        }  
    }

    return false;
}
```

Comment: It will be better if you could add the relevant HTML code also.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First look at the `filterCardsByRequirementsChoosed` function. You have both `for-of` and `for-in` loops, but are using them as though they're the same.

The `for-of` should be:

```
for(let card of jobCards){
 //   jobCards[card].style.display = "flex";
    card.style.display = "flex";
}
```

The `for-in` was done correctly, but using `for-of` is a little nicer IMO.

So it seemed you were just passing the wrong value to the function in question.

---

Actually, I do see that you're only calling the problem function in the `for-in` loop, and are passing the property name. So you seem to be doing that correctly.

One thing to keep in mind is that your `jobCards` is a *"live list"*. So if any of those elements get removed from the DOM, or even if the class you used to fetch them gets removed, those elements will be also removed from the `jobCards` list immediately.

Comment: For consistency the `for in` would be  better as `for of` also

Comment: Yes, I check the debuging, and the value given was "10" haha

I got confused with `for/in` and `for/of`` I've change another loop too, and then works.

And about the "live list", yeah, already know that, but the filter just is going to hide some elements temporary, and if the filters is cleaned, all elements get displayed again.

Thanks bro.

Answer (score 1):

in your loop

```
for(let card of jobCards)
```

card is your variable that will represent the elements in jobCards as they are being iterated through. It is not an index.

So you need to do

```
card.getElementByClassName(...)
card.style.display(...)
```

EDIT—
As per the comment below... you use the for in loop... which iterates over properties of the object. For an array... this will include the indices and other properties such as @length, etc giving you the error.

Comment: He's passing in the `card` index from the `for-in` loop, so `jobCards[card]` would be necessary.